# NPM command arguments

Tags: node.js, npm

Sorry I'm newbie in Nodejs and NPM, and I use this command (npm install -g ..) for What I need to install, OK after googled I couldn't figure it out what does -g do in NPM command or basically what does it mean?

Comment: Maybe you can read the [npm manual](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/npm) and answer to this question on your own.

Comment: ... especially [this page](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally) may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-g` is short for global. It installs the module [globally](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally) instead of in the current directory.

See this for more info:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/npm